# Decimal numbers in Numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe that looks like this -

```
     ID     NoNotifications NotificationsNot    total   Percent of people
    2544        272500          762              117         0.0
    2415        2288378        256575            655         0.0
    2558        192505         470610             7          0.0
```

I am running -

```
for index, row in percent.iterrows():
   print((117/300000)*100)
   row['Percent of people'] = row['total']/(row['NoNotifications'] + row['NotificationsNot'])*100
```

Why is it that the print statement is printing a decimal value with at least 3 precision points. For example, `0.039` but the second statement is only outputting `0.0` to `Percent of people` column.

**UPDATE**

I tried `row['Percent of people'] = (655/254495300*100)` and I am still getting a bunch of `0.0` in `Percent of people` column

**UPDATE 2**

Also, tried `repr((Decimal(655)/254495300*100))` and still the same thing.

Comment: What is your python version?

Comment: I think in second row, you are doing this `655/(2288378+256575)*100` = `655/superbignumber`

Comment: @YOLO I wouldn't consider 2 million is a super big number

Comment: @KevinFang actually it is 655/254495300

Comment: @yolo Just posted an update.

Comment: @Doe can you do (655/(2288378+256575))*100

Answer (score 0):

The column display is a result of the rendering function `__repr__` for a data frame.  This one happens to default to a single digit after the decimal point.  See the PANDAS documentation for details on changing this.

Your `print` statement uses the Python rendering for floats.  In this case, the rendering program recognizes that the last non-zero digit is in the 1000ths place, and truncates the display at that point.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a float formatter function as an argument to a dataframe's to_string method:

```
print(df.to_string(float_format=lambda f: '{:3.2e}%'.format(100 * f)))
```

would output `2.57e-04%`, while using `{:.4}%` would print `0.0003%`. The function above is a brief usable choice but you can make it as elaborate as you wish if you want to print e.g. '1.23%' for most values but use exponential notation for values beneath one hundredth of a percent.

Answer (score 0):

From [numpy docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html) -

```
import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)
```

will make sure that "always print floating point numbers using fixed point notation, in which case numbers equal to zero in the current precision will print as zero"

```
In[2]: import numpy as np

In[3]: np.array([1/50000000])
Out[3]: array([2.e-08])

In[4]: np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)
In[5]: np.array([1/50000000])
Out[5]: array([0.00000002])

In[6]: np.set_printoptions(precision=6)
In[7]: np.array([1/50000000])
Out[7]: array([0.])
```